# Livewire V3 / Laravel / Bootstrap - Off Canvas Disappears On Form Validation / Keeps Adding Darkened Backdrop On Wire:navigate options

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I've got 2 issues with my code using Livewire V3 and Laravel 10 with Bootstrap.

I've got an off canvas in which I include as a livewire component inside another livewire component.

I am using Livewires new navigate feature, however, each time I navigate away and back to the page it's including on the backdrop of the off canvas gets darker and each layer needs to be clicked away to access the page.

Also, when I submit the form (even if it has errors) it closes the off canvas, I've tried using `wire:ignore.self` which keeps it open but removes the backdrop it should have to seperate it from the page. Please see my code below, helps very much appreciated :).

**Child Component**

```
<div>
<button class="btn btn-alt-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#activateNewPetTag" aria-controls="activateNewPetTag">
    Activate New Pet Tag
</button>

<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end bg-body-extra-light" tabindex="-1" id="activateNewPetTag" aria-labelledby="activateNewPetTagLabel" wire:ignore.self>
    <div class="offcanvas-header bg-body-light">
        <div wire:loading class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-primary"></div>
        <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="activateNewPetTagLabel">Activate New Pet Tag</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <form wire:submit="activate">
            <x-forms.text-input type="text" placeholder="Activation Code" name="activationCode" />

            <div class="mt-4 mb-4">
                <x-forms.button title="Activate" class="alt-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Parent Component**

```
<livewire:user.pets.components.activate-pet-code />
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no more wire:ignore in new v
u can use @persist
read doc:
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/navigate#persisting-elements-across-page-visits

```
@persist('any_name')
    <div>your html code</div>
@endpersist
```

this div will not rerunder when you navigate to another page using livewire spa

for darker : you just need to add bootstrap.main.js in

```
<head>
bootstrap
</head>
```

that will call it just for one time
and you can do that with all css and js files
or you can use data-navigate-once like:

```
<script data-navigate-once>
    console.log('Runs only on page one')
</script>
```